# Spring Restful services GET and POST methods

Tags: restful-url

Probably a simple question on REST...

How do I pass the GET variables to the function in the below code

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/loginresult.json/{userid}/{pwd}")
{
public List<SecurityBean> getAuthenticationResult(){
    return authenticationAPI.getAuthenticationResult();
}
```

I wan't to pass the userid and pwd coming in url to the getAuthenticationResult() function

Also How can I pass POST parameters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for GET use `@QueryParam,`

for POSt use @`FormParam,`

for Cookie use `@CookieParam`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Yogesh...dont know why but was struggling to find a tutorial which tells this....really helpful

Comment: Please what is the equivalent of @FormParam in spring rest?

Answer (score 0):

Use following Code

```
@POST
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/loginresult.json/{userid}/{pwd}")
{
public List<SecurityBean> getAuthenticationResult(@FormParam("uName") String uName,@FormParam("pwd") String pwd){
    return authenticationAPI.getAuthenticationResult();
}
```

Comment: you mean CLient side using javascript or another ?

Comment: I mean to get GET parameter you have used @FormParam("uName") ...what shuld I use to get POST params?

Comment: For GET parameter you have to use @QueryParam("uName")... and for POST params use @FormParam("uName")